# Pairwise independence of Bernoulli Random Variable

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, random-variable

Let $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ be three bernoulli $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ random variables such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and $X$ and $Z$ are independent . Show that $$P(XYZ=0)=\frac{3}{4}$$
if and only if 
$ Z = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{if $X=Y$};\\
0 & \mbox{if $X\not=Y$}.\end{array} \right. $

Answer:-A raw attempt from my side :
We have,
$${XY=0}\subseteq {XYZ=0}\Rightarrow P(XY=0)\le P(XYZ=0)\Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}\le P(XYZ=0)$$
Here,  $P(XYZ=0)=\frac{3}{4}=P(XY=0)=P(YZ=0)=P(XZ=0)$ \
Consider first $$P(XYZ=0)=P(XY=0)$$

$\Longrightarrow P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)\\+P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)+P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)
\\+P(X=1,Y=0,Z=1)+P(X=1,Y=1,Z=0)$
$=P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+
P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)+
P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)
+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)+
P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)+
P(X=1,Y=0,Z=1)$

$$\Rightarrow P(X=1,Y=1,Z=0)=0..................(1)$$
Similarly,
$P(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)=P(X=1,Y=0,Z=1)=0.....(2)$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have 
${XYZ=0}$ iff the following three happens (other three as stated above is zero and all three being 1 is impossible) $$1)X=0,Y=0,Z=1$$
$$2)X=0,Y=1,Z=0$$
$$3)X=1,Y=0,Z=0$$
Again we have another $4^{th}$ possibility
$$4)X=0,Y=0,Z=0$$
Now,to show:- $$P(X=Y=Z=0)=0$$
Consider,
$$P(X=0,Y=0)=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$=P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)$$
So,$$P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)=\frac{1}{4}...............1)$$
Similarly,$$P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)=\frac{1}{4}........2)$$
and, $$P(X=0,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)=\frac{1}{4}...........3)$$
Adding (1),(2) and (3)
$$3.P(X=Y=Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)+P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)=\frac{3}{4}$$
But due to the question, we must have $$P(X=Y=Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=0,Z=1)+P(X=1,Y=0,Z=0)+P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)=\frac{3}{4}$$

Now it is obvious that $$P(X=Y=Z=0)=0$$. Therefore the remaining three posibilities viz.$(1)X=0,Y=0,Z=1$ ,$(2){X=0,Y=1,Z=0}$ and $3){X=1,Y=0,Z=0}$ can be formulated as $$ Z = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{if $X=Y$};\\
0 & \mbox{if $X\not=Y$}.\end{array} \right.$$

I would like to know whether my approach is correct.I will be happy if someone can point out my mistake.
I am also wondering if there is any short method to do the same.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question than asking whether what you did is right? It's not really within our remit to check your homework. For that, you should ask your teacher or a tutor.

Comment: You should add the self study tag.

Comment: For a question that can easily be answered by inspecting a small table of the eight possible combinations of $X,Y,Z$, the work in this post strikes me as being unnecessarily expansive.  Certainly few people would want to read it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

To facilitate the analysis, define the quantities:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
A_{x,y} &\equiv \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y), \\
p_{x,y} &\equiv \mathbb{P}(Z=1 | X=x, Y=y).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Since $X, Y \sim \text{IID Bern}(\frac{1}{2})$ we have $A_{x,y} = \frac{1}{4}$ for all $x, y = 0, 1$.  The remaining conditions of your question impose constraints on the values $p_{x,y}$ that allow us to determine these values.

---

**Marginal probability:** The requirement that $Z \sim \text{Bern}(\frac{1}{2})$ gives the constraint:

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(Z=1) = \sum_{x,y} A_{x,y} p_{x,y} = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{x,y} p_{x,y} & & & & \implies & & \sum_{x,y} p_{x,y} = 2.
\end{matrix}$$

**Pairwise independence:** Combined with the marginal probability requirement, the requirements that $X \bot Z$ and $Y \bot Z$ give the constraints:

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{4} = \mathbb{P}(X = x, Z=1) = \sum_{y} A_{x,y} p_{x,y} = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{y} p_{x,y} & & \implies & & \sum_{y} p_{x,y} = 1.
\end{matrix}$$

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{4} = \mathbb{P}(Y = y, Z=1) = \sum_{x} A_{x,y} p_{x,y} = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{x} p_{x,y} & & \implies & & \sum_{x} p_{x,y} = 1.
\end{matrix}$$

**Triple-product probability:** The requirement that $\mathbb{P}(XYZ = 0) = \frac{3}{4}$ gives the constraint:

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{4} = \mathbb{P}(XYZ = 1) = A_{1,1} p_{1,1} & & & & & & & & & \implies & & p_{1,1} = 1.
\end{matrix}$$

From these requirements we obtain the unique solution:

$$\begin{matrix}
p_{0,0} = 1 & & p_{0,1} = 0, \\
p_{1,0} = 0 & & p_{1,1} = 1.
\end{matrix}$$